# Log in into Ubuntu using a Windows machine like it was a new session

Tags: unity, 14.10

### Context

I have two machines at home

1. a laptop with Ubuntu Desktop 14.10
2. a laptop with Windows 7 Professional

The thing is that I used to use the Ubuntu machine a lot, but some time ago I forgot the laptop on the dinning table and my son took it and drop it on the ground...  as you might have inferred correctly, the screen was destroyed.  The funny thing is that I connected the laptop to my TV, and it was working properly - no damages other than the LCD screen.

As of today, the Ubuntu laptop is mainly used to watch Netflix and YouTube in the living room.

### What I want to do

I want to be able to connect to the Ubuntu machine using the Windows machine, but I don´t want to do it just by sharing the desktop screen...  Using **vnc** works ok, but I want to be able to login into the Ubuntu machine in a standalone session.  The reason for this is that I want to do some work *like I would do it when using the Ubuntu machine*, but without interferring with what the Ubuntu machine is currently doing.

For example, if my family is watching a movie using the Ubuntu laptop, I want to be able to login using my own session (even a different user), *a la NoMachine* style, and do some work without affecting the current session in the TV.  I mention NoMachine because that is what I have used in the past (back in the day of Gnome 2) to achieve the same, but as Ubuntu uses Unity, NoMachine does not work at all.

PS: I believe the name of this concept is *desktop virtualization*, but I couldn't find a tag like that in the tag selector.

PS 2: **I'd like to use Unity** as well, that is, not having to install another desktop environment like xfce or gnome.

Comment: It seems [tightvncserver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#tightvncserver) "creates a completely new desktop, not attached to any actual screen". Sounds like what you want.

Comment: Just tried it - somehow, I can create new *X desktops*, and can login into them using a really basic x window system...  however, I can't seem to find a way to go into the first X desktop, nor a login screen to enter Unity later on.

Comment: The "customizing" section that follows describes how  you can get you to a normal session, but I think `ubuntu-2d` should be replaced by `ubuntu`.

Comment: Try Chrome remote desktop. It works with unity now.

Comment: @user68186 will this create a new session, or it will just allow me to view the screen as any other regular VNC client?

Comment: I have not used it in the way you want, so I can't be sure. However, it may work if you have two users, one for your (remote) work, and the second for your family's TV viewing. Log into your work account locally first and setup Chrome for remote desktop access. Then log out and try to remotely access your work users account from  Chrome in the Windows laptop. If this works I will write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VNC Server to accomplish this.
You will want to run a Virtual Mode session on the laptop (either write an init.d file, or add a cron job for when powered on).
Configure this to use the LXDE or XFCE desktop environment ([instructions here](https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/345)) and you can then connect using IP:1 from another machine with a viewer, and it will not interfere with the console session being shown on the TV.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, I rather not install a new desktop environment but use what is currently installed (Unity).

Comment: Unity requires specific hardware features of the graphics card, which can't be called by a virtual session, I do not know of a method which will allow you a separate graphical session whilst retaining the ability to use Unity.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!  That could be the reason why I'm not finding information regarding Unity as a virtual desktop, and also why NoMachine is failing to work as well.

Comment: I would expect that is the main reason, yes. personally I use LXDE when creating virtual sessions on ubuntu boxes, to the point where I use it more often than unity. Most DWMs will work well for this though, so gnome or kde are also options